# Validating a form server side - ASP.NET Core 2.2 Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a form which I have been validating with the standard [Required] helper tags.

I needed to add validation to see if the entry was already in AD, so I used:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(){

 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {

        return Page();
     }

if (MyADClass.Exists(Model.id)){

    Error = "An account already exists for" + Model.id;

    return RedirectToPage(new { message = Error });
}

//Else do stuff

}
```

The problem with this approach, is that it refreshes the whole page and loses the values currently in the form. What is the easiest way to preform the validation after the user has clicked submit, but without losing the model data?

Comment: Can't you return the page but with the model data in it? You can in MVC. E.g. `return Page(model);`.

Comment: And for your custom error you could actually add that to the modelstate collection, then it becomes part of the main validation process

Comment: I dont think that return Page(model); is valid syntax in razor pages? I add the error to the model - but only if I can pass it back to the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realised I could just set the Message directly as part of the model and call return Page();

Thanks @ADyson